# How to Create a Column of Unique ID-Year-Date combinations from a dataframe

Tags: r

I have a set of annual animal tracking data and I would like to create a column of unique days tracked for each individual-year combination. My data looks something like this:

```
'''r
ID<-c(1,1,1,2,2,2)
Year<-c(2004,2004,2005,2004,2005,2005)
Date<-(c("2004-01-23","2004-04-12","2005-06-13","2004-04-05","2005-01-12","2005-01-12"))
Date<-as.Date(Date)
df<-data.frame(ID,Year,Date)
'''r
```

| ID | Year | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2004 | 2004-01-23 |
| 1 | 2004 | 2004-04-12 |
| 1 | 2005 | 2005-06-13 |
| 2 | 2004 | 2004-04-05 |
| 2 | 2005 | 2005-01-12 |
| 2 | 2005 | 2005-01-12 |

What I would like to do now is create a dataframe of id-year combinations using the group_by() function in dplyr and add a column for total unique days tracked. For example, since individual 2 was tracked twice on 2005-01-12 those two columns would only count as one:

| ID | Year | Unique Days |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2004 | 2 |
| 1 | 2005 | 1 |
| 2 | 2004 | 1 |
| 2 | 2005 | 1 |

So far I've managed to use duplicated() to find which id-year-date combinations have been duplicated:

```
'''r
duplicates<-df[duplicated(df[,1:3]),]
'''r
```

but I don't know how to use that code to create the new column, if that's even the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

The `summarize` function in `dplyr` makes it easy to get numeric summaries. Try the `n_unique` [function](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/n_distinct.html):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(ID, Year) %>%
  summarize(“Unique Rows” = n_distinct(Date))
```

Comment: `n_distinct` instead of `n_unique`?

Comment: I tried working with the n_distinct function and ended up with the following: unique_rows<-df %>%
group_by(ID, Year) %>%
summarize("Unique Rows" = n_distinct(Date))                                                        Which seems to work. Thanks!